# not able run nutch in netbeans?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, nutch

I dont know which path to give under "Web page" and "WEB-INF" folder..

I tried to give the path "tomcat/webapps/roots/WEB-INF" under WEB-INF

Under source i gave the path to the "src" folder which was kept in nutch1.4 source folder...

and to lib, the path given is "lib" folder under nutch1.4 bin folder....

the build was successful but when i run it....it displays the following exception!!!

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()   [Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;

 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:272)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
```

where the root cause is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$2.acceptResult(JDTCompiler.java:341)
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:398)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:399)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:288)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:267)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:255)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:293)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to run? a JSP page or are you trying to invoke a servlet? instead of posting exceptions its better to post code so we could tell you whats wrong with your code

Comment: dude, there's nothing wrong with the code.
I,till now, havent customized the nutch source code.